# Orthographic world projection, how to detect if the point is on the back side

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I'm trying to make orthographic projection of the world map. I use this common equations:

$$\begin{cases}x&=&\cos \phi \sin(\lambda - \lambda_0)\\
y&=&\cos \phi_1 \sin \phi - \sin \phi_1 \cos \phi \cos(\lambda - \lambda_0)\end{cases}$$

I have something like this globe:

[image]

How can I detect if the point (long, lat) is on the front side of the globe or not? (I want to hide the points from the back side)

I have latitude, longitude and reference point (lambda0 and phi1 params).

Thanks.

Update. Range examples (boundary cases):

[image: range examples]

So ideally I need a rule that describes these ranges.

Comment: Hey, what format is your data? I assume you have each country as a series of points that define its border? If they are all clockwise or counterclockwise for example, there are some quick tricks you could do to compute which way they are facing (toward you or away).  How would you want to handle countries which are partly facing you and partly facing away (like Russia here)?

Comment: If the line through the poles is parallel to the image plane, you can simply find the longitude of the “slice” through the center of the globe parallel to the image plane and do a simple range check.

Comment: @orlandpm Yes, each country is a series of points. I have not yet come to an ideal decision about how to handle cases with partly facing (still there are some rendering issues). Currently I want to place all points from the backside on the edge of the globe. Ie flatten part of the country, which should not be visible.

Comment: @amd It depends on the reference point. As far as I understand, there are some boundary cases.    


For example: 
**1) reference point: longitude = 0, latitude = 0**
_In that case range: -pi/2 < latitude < pi/2 and -pi/2 < longitude < pi/2_
**2) reference point: longitude = 0, latitude = pi/2**
_In that case range: 0 < latitude < pi/2 and -pi < longitude < pi_
**3) reference point: longitude = 0, latitude = -pi/2**
_In that case range: -pi/2 < latitude < 0 and -pi < longitude < pi._

So ideally I need a rule that describes these ranges.

Comment: So, what exactly do you mean exactly by “reference point?” All we had to go on before your edit was the single view of the globe. After your update, it’s still not entirely clear to me what it is you want here.